# search a particular string and remove all the remaining after that string

Tags: sed

This is the file.

```
scr  PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.13394141
prog PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.16077702
sch PI Name: RRC Access Failures due to UU, Value: 0.11781933
```

I want to search `Failures` and remove the remaining strings in that line.

My output should be,

```
scr  PI Name: RRC Access Failures
prog PI Name: RRC Access Failures
sch PI Name: RRC Access Failures
```

I tried `sed` command, but it is deleting entire line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed` again.

```
$ sed  's/Failures.*$/Failures/' file
```

This substitutes everything from the string `Failures` to the end of the line with the word `Failures`.  I has the effect of removing everything after `Failures`.

Comment: I think the regex should be `Failures.*$` instead of `Failures*.$`, right?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio Yep. I just woke up...